# Jquery Mobile DateBox is not showing time picker if created dynamically

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

I am using Jquery Mobile DateBox plugin for date/time picker in my cordova Application. It works fine if written as it is HTML file. The problem comes if I clone a div which has DateBox input and append it to another div. Time picker is not poping up on tap of timer icon.

The div which I am cloning is,

```
<div class="time-picker-template">

    <input class="time-input day-time-picker" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useNewStyle":true}' />

</div>
```

The way I clone is ,

```
var dayTimePicker = $("#page-add-reminder .time-picker-template").clone();

$("#page-add-reminder #time-picker-block").append(dayTimePicker);
```

It renders the DateBox input field but it is disabled. When I inspect the element, It shows,

```
<input class="time-input day-time-picker" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options="{"mode":"timebox", "useNewStyle":true}" readonly="readonly">
```

I suspect the readonly property initially but the input field will be readonly only. On tap of time icon which resides next to input field filled the time in other case.

I compared the DOM element of both cloned element and general TimeBox element. Both looks same. The first didn't work but the later works. Where am I missing ? Can any suggest me how to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cloning the datebox, you should put your templates outside the page so that jQM does not enhance then before you clone and add them to the page.  Here is a working demo:

```
<div id="templates">
    <div class="time-picker-template">
        <input class="time-input day-time-picker" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useNewStyle":true}' />
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <button id="btnAdd">Add timepicker from template</button>
        <div id="time-picker-block"></div>
    </div> 
</div>  

$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){     
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){
        var dayTimePicker = $("#templates .time-picker-template").clone();
        $("#time-picker-block").append(dayTimePicker).enhanceWithin();        
    });
});
```

When you click the button, the un-enhanced template is cloned and added to the page, then we call enhanceWithin() to tell jQM to ehance the controls within the block.

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ggd7vzqc/)**

You could also have your template as a string in the script.